# Jquery custom scrollspy active nav item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a custom scrollspy for a website.

When scroll down I want first of all make the nav fixed/sticky, that works perfectly. When scroll down further I try to make the current nav item active, by adding a class `active`.

But whatever I try I just can't get that class `active` added to the nav item when we are at that specific section. I don't get any errors whatsoever so I rerally don't know anymore what I do wrong. I just can't see it.

Is this perhaps the wrong approach or can someone see why it won't get active?

```js
$(function() {
  var $anchor = $('.product-menu');
  if ($anchor.length) {
    var $menuItems = $anchor.find('a'),
      $scrollItems = $menuItems.map(function() {
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) {
          return item;
        }
      }),
      initPosition = $anchor.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var htop = $('#header').outerHeight(true) - 1;
      if (initPosition != $anchor.offset().top && !$anchor.hasClass('sticky')) {
        initPosition = $anchor.offset().top;
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= initPosition - htop) {
        $anchor.addClass("sticky").css({
          top: htop
        });
      } else {
        $anchor.removeClass("sticky");
      }
      if ($anchor.length && $(window).width() > 768) {
        var cur = $scrollItems.map(function() {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top - $anchor.outerHeight() - $('#header').outerHeight()) return this;
        });
        cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
        var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
        $menuItems.removeClass("active").end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").addClass("active");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
  background: indianred;
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 98;
  transition: all ease-in-out .25s;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.product-menu {
  margin: 45px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--border);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border);
  height:60px;
  line-height:60px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.product-menu.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-inline {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-inline li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.product-block {
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div class="header flex flex-align-center flex-between container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="" alt="Logo" width="" height="64" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav id="menu" class="nav list-inline">
      <ul class="list-inline container">
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="some-container">
    <nav class="product-menu">
      <ul class="list-inline container">
        <li><a href="#description" class="goSmoothly">Product information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#specifications" class="goSmoothly">Specifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bundles" class="goSmoothly">Product bundles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#reviews" class="goSmoothly">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#related" class="goSmoothly">Related products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="desc">
      <div id="description" class="product-block">description</div>
      <div id="specifications" class="product-block">specifications</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div id="bundles" class="product-block">bundles</div>
      <div id="reviews" class="product-block">reviews</div>
    </div>
    <div id="related" class="product-block">related</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You say you have the sticky nav working, but it is not working in your example here. Can you update the snippet with the code you have that works, please? Otherwise if there is something wrong/missing in this code it could affect any answers we give you.

Comment: @FluffyKitten: You are right. Forgot to hit save for the snippet. It's working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty rough but might help you get you to where you want. Defiantly not the most efficient way to handle this.

I changed `$(window).width() > 768` greater than value to `520` so example below would run in stackoverflow desktop.

I've include comments in my newly added code below...

```js
$(function() {

  // changed this to const variable and non object var
  const anchor = $('.product-menu');

  // set updatable vars on ready
  let scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  let topOffset = anchor.outerHeight() + $('#header').outerHeight();

  // if product menu nav exists
  if (anchor.length) {

    // re arranged vars a bit
    let $menuItems = $('a', anchor);
    let $scrollItems;

    // update scroll items var
    $scrollItems = $menuItems.map(function() {
      let item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) {
        return item;
      }
    });

    let initPosition = anchor.offset().top;

    // added this so when product menu items are clicked it scrolls to div
    $menuItems.on('click', function(e) {

      // get the href id from the clicked anchor
      let anchor = $(this).attr('href');

      // get the scroll to (top) position minus the nav
      let scrollTo = $(anchor).offset().top - topOffset;

      // scroll too
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo
      }, 1000);

      // prevent link defaults
      e.preventDefault();

    });

    // changed this to .on binding method instead of .scroll
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {

      let htop = $('#header').outerHeight(true) - 1;
      if (initPosition != anchor.offset().top && !anchor.hasClass('sticky')) {
        initPosition = anchor.offset().top;
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= initPosition - htop) {
        anchor.addClass("sticky").css({
          top: htop
        });
      } else {
        anchor.removeClass("sticky");
      }

      // update vars on scroll
      scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
      topOffset = anchor.outerHeight() + $('#header').outerHeight();

      // changed 768 to 520 so stackoverflow demo would fire
      if (anchor.length && $(window).width() > 520) {

        // each scroll items for key value function
        $.each($scrollItems, function(key, value) {

          // if the top offset minus the scroll top position is less than or equal to header + product menu height
          if ((value.offset().top - scrollTop) <= topOffset) {

            // remove class from all product menu item anchors
            $menuItems.removeClass('active');

            // add active class to current viewed product menu anchor
            $('a[href="#' + this.attr('id') + '"]', anchor).addClass('active');

          }

        });

      }


    });
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
  background: indianred;
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 98;
  transition: all ease-in-out .25s;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.product-menu {
  margin: 45px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--border);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border);
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.product-menu.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-inline {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-inline li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.product-block {
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.product-menu a.active {
  color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div class="header flex flex-align-center flex-between container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="" alt="Logo" width="" height="64" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav id="menu" class="nav list-inline">
      <ul class="list-inline container">
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="some-container">
    <nav class="product-menu">
      <ul class="list-inline container">
        <li><a href="#description" class="goSmoothly active">Product information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#specifications" class="goSmoothly">Specifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bundles" class="goSmoothly">Product bundles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#reviews" class="goSmoothly">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#related" class="goSmoothly">Related products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="desc">
      <div id="description" class="product-block">description</div>
      <div id="specifications" class="product-block">specifications</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div id="bundles" class="product-block">bundles</div>
      <div id="reviews" class="product-block">reviews</div>
    </div>
    <div id="related" class="product-block">related</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @joshmoto: Thx for your answer... I will try it. One question though, why is this an inefficient way of doing this? What would be a more efficient way then?

Comment: Because I'm checking each section the distance from the top, I guessing if you have like over a 100 sections, it might start to lag, but this seems to work ok but there might be a better way to do it i'm just not sure how.

Comment: @joshmoto: Not exactly what I wanted, but I gonna give the bounty for your great effort :) It at least helped me to fix the issue. The "issue" with your code is that 2 blocks with an id are positioned on one line on the same height. So clicking "reviews" will make "bundles" active aswell. Giving one block a 1 px margin doesn't solve the whole problem, but anyway I fixed it differently now. Thx for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

After some minor modifications only in this part of your code.

```
if ($anchor.length && $(window).width() > 768) {
...
}
```

The menu element will remain active while scrolling in the area covered by the element's height, you can check the desired behavior by running the code snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  var $anchor = $('.product-menu');
  if ($anchor.length) {
    var $menuItems = $anchor.find('a'),
      $scrollItems = $menuItems.map(function() {
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) {
          return item;
        }
      }),
      initPosition = $anchor.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var htop = $('#header').outerHeight(true) - 1;
      if (initPosition != $anchor.offset().top && !$anchor.hasClass('sticky')) {
        initPosition = $anchor.offset().top;
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= initPosition - htop) {
        $anchor.addClass("sticky").css({
          top: htop
        });
      } else {
        $anchor.removeClass("sticky");
      }
      if ($anchor.length) {
        Array.from($scrollItems).forEach(($scrollItem, i) => {
          let id = $($scrollItem).attr('id');
          let bottomOffsetMargin;
          if(i < $scrollItems.length -1 ) {
            bottomOffsetMargin = $($scrollItems[i+1]).offset().top;
          } else {
            bottomOffsetMargin = $anchor.offset().top + $anchor.outerHeight();
          }
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $($scrollItem).offset().top && $(window).scrollTop() < bottomOffsetMargin && !$anchor.find("a[href='#" + id + "']").hasClass("active")) {
            $menuItems.removeClass("active");
            $anchor.find("a[href='#" + id + "']").addClass("active");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
  background: indianred;
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 98;
  transition: all ease-in-out .25s;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.product-menu {
  margin: 45px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--border);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border);
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.product-menu.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-inline {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-inline li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.product-block {
  height: 500px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

a.goSmoothly.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div class="header flex flex-align-center flex-between container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="" alt="Logo" width="" height="64" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav id="menu" class="nav list-inline">
      <ul class="list-inline container">
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="goSmoothly">Main nav item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="some-container">
    <nav class="product-menu">
      <ul class="list-inline container">
        <li><a href="#description" class="goSmoothly">Product information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#specifications" class="goSmoothly">Specifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bundles" class="goSmoothly">Product bundles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#reviews" class="goSmoothly">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#related" class="goSmoothly">Related products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="desc">
      <div id="description" class="product-block">description</div>
      <div id="specifications" class="product-block">specifications</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div id="bundles" class="product-block">bundles</div>
      <div id="reviews" class="product-block">reviews</div>
    </div>
    <div id="related" class="product-block">related</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```